# Ubuntu installation editor not showing partition

Tags: system-installation, 15.04, partitioning

I am trying to install ubuntu 15.04 in my desktop. I already have windows 8.1 loaded. I made a partition of 200gb. But when I'm trying to install ubuntu in that partition, whole hard disk is showing(1TB), exclusively no partition is showing. What to do?

Comment: How did you format the partition? Ubuntu can't be installed on NTFS (the windows default). When the Ubuntu installer asks you for the installation type select "Something else", can you reformat the partition there?

Comment: @Minos I'm selecting something else and there whole hard disk is showing as one, no partition. Yes I formatted with NTFS. Should I unallocate and try to install Ubuntu then?

Comment: Yes if your hard disk shows up properly I would just try again. I assume you already have a backup of your windows 8.1 partition? To find out how you can resize the existing partition from the Ubuntu installer, you can use the answers to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation